# Self-intersection number of fibered surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

Let $R$ be a complete discrete valuation ring with residue field $k$ (can assume algebraically closed), $f:X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ a flat, proper family of projective curves (i.e., $f$ is also surjective and $X$ is a projective surface). Assume further that $X$ is non-singular. Denote by $Y$ the special fiber $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec}(k))$. Is there any way to compute the self-intersection of $Y$? Is there some literature which deals with similar questions? If necessary one can assume the generic fiber of $f$ is smooth.

Comment: I don't have it on hand, but if it's somewhere accessible, it'll be in chapter 9 of Qing Liu.

Comment: I don't really understand the assertion that $X$ is a projective surface. $X$ is projective over ${\rm Spec}(R)$, but only of relative dimension 1.

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}R$ is of dimension $1$.

Comment: Thank you Youcis. I think Proposition $1.21$ on page $384$ of Qing Liu answers my question.

Comment: I know Spec R is of dimension 1. And I agree that X is of dimension 2. And the morphism is projective. But X is not a projective surface.